# Express $\;f(x)=\frac{x − 1}{x + 1}\;$ as the sum of an even and an odd function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In homework there is such problem:

> Express $\;f(x)=\dfrac{x − 1}{x + 1}\;$ as the sum of an even and an odd function.
>   (Simplify as much as possible.)

This function is not even and neither odd. Also if we take it as division of 2 functions, neither $x - 1$ nor $x + 1$ are odd or even... so I'm confused...

Comment: The sum of an even function and an odd function doesn't need to be even or odd (e.g. $x+x^2$).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define

- $f_e(x) = \frac12\left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)$
- $f_o(x) = \frac12\left(f(x)-f(-x)\right)$

Then $f_e$ is *even* and $f_o$ is *odd* and $f_e+f_o=f$ for any given $f$

In your special case $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$, so
$$f_e(x) = \frac12\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1} + \frac{-x-1}{-x+1} \right) = \ldots$$
$$f_o(x) = \frac12\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1} - \frac{-x-1}{-x+1} \right) = \ldots$$
you just have to simplify.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late, but you could also simply multiply both numerator and denominator by $(x-1)$.
$$ \begin{align} 
  \frac{x-1}{x+1} &= \frac{x-1}{x+1} \cdot \frac{x-1}{x-1} \\
  &= \frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2-1} \\
  &= \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} + \frac{2x}{1-x^2} \\
\end{align} $$

The left-hand term is even since it is of the form $even/even$, and the right-hand term is odd since it has the form $odd/even$.